# Reduce computations required to count by multiples in C

Tags: arrays, c

Im trying to count by multiples of `x` in a `uint8_t` c-array. Such that whenever the multiples of `x` overflows the 256 limit, it increases in the next category, similar to the hands of a clock or counting in binary. If `x` were 80, an example might be:

```
(0,   0,  0)  ->  0
(80,  0,  0)  ->  1
(160, 0,  0)  ->  2
(240, 0,  0)  ->  3
(0,   80, 0)  ->  4
...
```

so far, I have been able to achieve it using these sets of equations:

```
uint16_t get_max(uint8_t bound){
  return (255+bound)/bound;
}

static void bind(uint32_t val, uint8_t bound, uint8_t rgb[3]){
  uint16_t max = bound*get_max(bound);

  rgb[0] = (val*bound)%max;
  rgb[1] = (((val*bound)/max)*bound)%max;
  rgb[2] = (((((val*bound)/max)*bound)/max)*bound)%max;
}
```

however, I feel as though a lot of these equations seem unnessecary for such a simple task. Is there a more efficient way to achieve this I'm overlooking?

Comment: From your example, this is equivalent to converting to base `ceil(256/x)`, where the digits are then multiplied by `x`.

Comment: use a single `uint32_t` with bit shifting and masking: `rgb[0] = val & 0xff; rgb[1] = (val >> 8) & 0xff; ... `?

Comment: How is the function you showed relevant to the function? Is `val` or `bound` the variable `x` which is `80`? And why does `rgb[1]` do not depend on `rgb[0]` - doesn't it get overflowed?

Comment: @KamilCuk i can see you're confused, thats okay. `val` is the number to be counted up to. `bound` is the multiple by which it will count with (aka x), and it doesn't overflow since each equation is modulo'd by `max`. =)

Comment: But you showed. `(240, 0,  0)  ->  3`, shouldn't it be `(3, 80) -> (240, 0, 0)`, where the pair `(3, 80)` represents `val` and `bound`?

Comment: @KamilCuk i already specified that i was counting by 80 above, I think adding another digit to the pair would confuse people. It seemed decently clear that the number on the right was showing what iteration the numbers on the left are representing

Comment: @yano im confused, how exactly would i use this to count up to a number in multiples of another? I tried implementing it and perhaps I did so wrong but I could not get it to achieve the desired effect

Comment: MintyFreshChicken, If you really want a faster solution, also post a test engine to assess functionality and score the performance.  I am sure here or maybe on Code Review, you would get some competitive results.

Comment: think I initially misunderstood. I'm not understanding how you're getting from 3 to 4 in your above example. Add 80 to 240 and that overflows 255, I get that, but how does that result in `(0, 80, 0)`? I would've expected (240+80) % 256 --> `(64, 1, 0)`, or perhaps even `(0, 64, 0)`. Can you flesh out some more iterations, at least to 10 would be nice, and maybe further explain what's supposed to happen at these rollover events?

Comment: As it looks now, you've only got 9 events. What happens next after `(0, 0, 240) --> 9`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you may be looking for something like the following. If not, you need to clarify the task.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


enum { NCounters = 3 }; //  Number of elements in the counter array.


/*  Add increment to the given counter.  If it does not overflow, return 0.
    If it overflows, reset the counter to 0 and report a carry.
*/
int AddOne(uint8_t increment, uint8_t counters[1])
{
    unsigned a = counters[0] + increment;
    if (256 <= a)
    {
        counters[0] = 0;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        counters[0] = a;
        return 0;
    }
}


/*  Add increment to the counters, starting with the lowest counter and
    proceeding to higher counters as long as there is a carry.  If it does not
    overflow out of all the counters, return 0.  If it overflows, report a
    carry.
*/
int Add(uint8_t increment, uint8_t counters[NCounters])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NCounters; ++i)
        if (!AddOne(increment, &counters[i]))
            return 0;
    return 1;
}


int main(void)
{
    //  Initialize counters to zero.
    uint8_t counters[NCounters] = { 0 };

    /*  Repeatedly print the counters and add the increment until the add
        reports a carry out of the counters.
    */
    do
    {
        printf("(%3d", counters[0]);
        for (size_t i = 1; i < NCounters; ++i)
            printf(", %3d", counters[i]);
        printf(")\n");
    } while (!Add(80, counters));
}
```

Comment: is this really less computationally expensive than my original suggested solution?

Comment: @MintyFreshChicken If cost to do `/` or `%` is high, then this is a good solution.